# UGF Wire in Conduit

Tags: electrical

The previous homeowner of a property I recently bought ran 8ga UGF 4 wire to an outbuilding. The wire comes up 4' out of the ground to daylight and into a junction box on the side of the building. I would like to place this wire inside sched 80 conduit to protect it from weed whacking etc. Should I just go ahead and insert the wire as is into the appropriate size conduit or do I need to strip the sheathing off before installing.  The wire is located on a wall that receives direct sunlight in the summer.

Answer (score 2):

You do not want to strip the insulation/sheathing off the cables before putting them into conduit. Those cables are not rated for use like that. Make sure to install the riser conduit 18" below grade for additional protection.

Comment: I asked about this because I looked at the other end of the line which is in conduit where it enters the house and found it was in 1" conduit and the sheathing had been stripped back about 16 inches to make it fit.  Is there any remedy to this short of digging everything up and making an underground waterproof splice so close to the end of the run? Is it a factor of the wires not having enough insulation?  Can I buy fiberglass or silicone or rubber sleeves to put on them and install back inside larger diameter conduit?  If the labor and expense of a splice is the only way to go then so be it.

Comment: Personally, I'd leave it as is.  If  the cable was terminated in a breaker or meter panel, you'd be allowed to strip the sheathing off at least that much to route the wires to breakers and bus bars. You're not allowed to strip it off but you're not required to fix it if you find it unless you've got a really picky inspector.

Comment: Awesome.  This has been in place I'm guessing probably at least five or six years, so no issues with it. But would it still be a good idea to put the wires inside a larger diameter conduit? Thanks

Comment: @CommanderDavid   The  1" conduit will be fine. You can fit 9 - #8 AWG THWN  in  a 1" rigid conduit.  We don't know what type of insulation is on the wires because they're not marked when in sheathing but this give a rough estimate.

Answer (score 2):

You are forbidden from stripping the sheathing off.  The sheathing is required for it to be certified for use outdoors, it provides weather protection.  Inside a conduit outdoors *is outdoors*.

The root of your problem is that UF cable is a very flat, wide cable.  That means you will need large conduit for it.

However, you are only using conduit as a handy anti-weedwacker damage shield, not as a proper *wiring method*. As such, you can use any material that suffices for a damage shield, you don't need to use approved electrical conduit.  And even better, you don't need to follow the conduit fill rules (which would have required conduit inside diameter to be 138% of the widest width of the cable).

Feel free to enter the house the normal way with an LB, using any conduit size that can physically fit the cable. I see 8/3 UF-B as 1.059" wide. Schedule 80 is a bit small of nominal because of wall thickness, but 1-1/4" Sched 80 will suffice.  If you had to follow conduit rules, 1-1/2" would be required.